# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails using eloquent

Tags: php, orm, eloquent, slim

I get this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

when I add a todo, however when I do this via on `mysql` like the following I get the following

> mysql>  INSERT INTO tasks (task, created_at, user_id) VALUES ('owls
>   are cool', CURTIME(),1); Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

And it shows in my database fine, but it doesn't work when I do it within my controller which is linked to route.

This is using eloquent in slim php by the way

Any suggestions

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

use App\Models\Task;
use App\Models\User;



class HomeController extends BaseController
{

    public function index($request, $response)
    {


        return $this->c->view->render($response, 'home.twig');

    }

    public function addTask($request, $response) {
        $input = $request->getParsedBody();
        $sql = new Task();

        $options = array(
            'options' => array(
                'default' => 3, // value to return if the filter fails
                // other options here
                'min_range' => 0
            ),
            'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_BACKTICK,
        );

        $sql->task = filter_var($input['task'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, $options);


        $sql->save();
        return $response->write($sql->toJson())->withRedirect('/todos');
    }
```

Comment: What is $input? Why is there a task on Task? very confusing!

Comment: @Scriptonomy i have been figuring things out with your guidance, my main question  is how do i add a new task associated with the user ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it had to change my add task controller to this

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

use App\Models\Task;
use App\Models\User;

use App\Auth\Auth;

class HomeController extends BaseController
{

    public function index($request, $response)
    {


        return $this->c->view->render($response, 'home.twig');

    }

    public function addTask($request, $response) {

        $data = $request->getParsedBody();
        $task = Task::create([
            'task' => $data['task'],   // $request->title also works?
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->user_id   // there might be a better solution, but this works 100%
        ]);

        var_dump($task);

        return $response->write($task->toJson())->withRedirect('/todos');
    }
```